# How to pass difference type into a function like passing variables

Tags: c#, wpf

DatePickerOfItemsControl, TextBoxOfItemsControl, ComboBoxOfItemsControl are class, how to pass these class into a function like passing variables

for the function to save these class or type as a variable and use it to create instance when needed

```
ifactory.AddControl(DatePickerOfItemsControl);
ifactory.AddControl(TextBoxOfItemsControl);
//ifactory.AddControl(textbox2);
ifactory.AddControl(ComboBoxOfItemsControl);
ifactory.AddControl(RadioBoxOfItemsControl);

public void AddControl(Object c)
{
    datepickerclass = DatePickerOfItemsControl;


public void Apply()
{
     datepickerclass datepicker = new datepickerclass();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Type`:

```
public void AddControl(Type c)
{

}
```

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to then create an instance of the type:

```
public void AddControl(Type c)
{
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(c);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
AddControl(typeof(RadioBoxOfItemsControl));
```

See MSDN -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: after use object o = Activator.CreateInstance(c);, it return Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Use ifactory.AddControl(typeof(DatePickerOfItemsControl)); etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but I think your trying to generalise the creation of controls so how about something like this:

```
ifactory.AddControl(() => { new datepickerclass() });

public void AddControl<T>(Func<T> factory)
    where T : BaseControlType
{
    var instanceOfControl = factory();
```